# Converting Date From TextBox To Date In ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to get the difference of date from Two TextBox say to and from dates..

My Code is here

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan            
ts = CDate(txtTo.Text) - CDate(txtFrom.Text)
txtDays.Text = ts.Days() + 1
```

but this code is throwing an error like this

```
Conversion from string "16/11/2011" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, try to avoid using old VB functions like `CDate`. In this case, you should use the `Parse` method:

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan
ts = DateTime.Parse(txtTo.Text) - DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text)
```

Or, if you know the date format in advance:

```
Dim fmt As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Dim ts As TimeSpan
ts = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTo.Text, fmt, Nothing) - DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text, fmt, Nothing)
```

Comment: its throwing a error like this `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: It's likely that you have to specify the appropriate date format. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using ParseExact like:

```
    Dim s As String = txtFrom.Text.trim
    Dim pattern As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    Dim parsedDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(s, pattern, Nothing)
```

As that way you can specify the format of the string that is used.

More direct to your example:

```
Dim pattern As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
ts = Date.ParseExact(txtTo.Text, pattern, Nothing) - Date.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text, pattern, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly cast a string to DateTime. You need to use the DateTime.Parse function to parse a string to a DateTime.

The syntax can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx#Y0).

Comment: its throwing a error like this `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: My Date Format is dd/mm/yyyy like 29/11/2011 Indian Date Format

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded version of the function:

```
 DateTime value = DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text,  new CultureInfo("gu-IN", false));
```

where "gu-IN" is for Gujarati (India)